# Let ray automatically assign a GPU per task

Tags: python, ray

I am using ray (https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run a task that feeds images into the Inception v3 net, loaded from tensorflow.keras. My task looks as follows (simplified):

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3

@ray.remote
def predict(image):
    model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, pooling='avg', input_shape=(1920, 1080, 3))
    return model.predict(image)
```

My machine has 8 GPUs, but I don't get ray to assign the task to all GPUs. If I set

```
ray.init(num_gpus=8)
```

it doesn't seem to assign 1 Task per GPU.

My question: How can I make ray to automatically assign one task per GPU, i.e. parallelize prediction for all my images over all available GPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ray.remote(num_gpus=1)
def predict(image):
    model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, pooling='avg', input_shape=(1920, 1080, 3))
    return model.predict(image)
```

Should work. See https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-ray-with-gpus.html#using-remote-functions-with-gpus